# Grunt Build not working with Bower-installed components

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, gruntjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to run

```
grunt build
```

from within a directory that was created by

```
yo angular
```

I installed angular-ui-bootstrap via bower. Locally I needed to add

```
<script src="components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

to my index.html and

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap'])
```

to my app.js. However every time I try to build the app I get this error

Error: No module: ui.bootstrap
        at Error ()
        at /Users/nicholasshook/angular/pokerfund/angular_app/app/components/angular/angular.js:1104:17
        at ensure (/Users/nicholasshook/angular/pokerfund/angular_app/app/components/angular/angular.js:1045:38)
        at module (/Users/nicholasshook/angular/pokerfund/angular_app/app/components/angular/angular.js:1102:14)
        at /Users/nicholasshook/angular/pokerfund/angular_app/app/components/angular/angular.js:2768:24
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at forEach (/Users/nicholasshook/angular/pokerfund/angular_app/app/components/angular/angular.js:131:11)
        at loadModules (/Users/nicholasshook/angular/pokerfund/angular_app/app/components/angular/angular.js:2764:5)
        at /Users/nicholasshook/angular/pokerfund/angular_app/app/components/angular/angular.js:2769:38
        at Array.forEach (native)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'awesomeThings' of undefined
        at null. (/Users/nicholasshook/angular/pokerfund/angular_app/test/spec/controllers/main.js:20:17)

Comment: Show the bower command you used to add ui-bootstrap please

Comment: bower install angular-bootstrap

Comment: I have also tried installing angular-bootstrap via bower.json and bower install fwiw

Comment: I had to add --save to the bower install to ensure the bower_components we added to my project 
bower install --save angular-bootstrap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have installed ui-bootstrap via bower, you will also need to update your `karma.conf.js` in order to make the grunt tests pass.

Add an entry for `ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js` in the file `karma.conf.js`:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'app/components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
];
```

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

1. Confirm that when you did your bower install the files were successfully downloaded from their repositories and in fact added to your file structure at the location you list in your script tag, namely `components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js`.
2. Confirm proper order for your script tags, namely your `<script src="components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>` tag needs to be listed PRIOR to your `<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>`.  If not, that would explain why the app.js can't find the module 'ui.bootstrap'.

Hope one of those helps you. I used the `bower install angular-bootstrap` and had no issues.

Comment: thanks for the answer did grunt build work for you? as an awful hack, I just put angular-ui and angular-ui-bootstrap in a lib folder within my scripts directory

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if `karma.conf.js` is not the culprit, verify that any new libraries you add are registered in grunt's `build.config.js` under `vendor_files`. That was my issue.